# Can’t run docker containers in linux CentOS, how to fix it?

Tags: centos, docker, alpine-linux

Can’t run docker containers in linux CentOS, how to fix it?

```
[root@mycentos ~]# docker run alpine
container_linux.go:235: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:258: applying cgroup configuration for process caused \"Cannot set property TasksAccounting, or unknown property.\""
/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:235: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:258: applying cgroup configuration for process caused \"Cannot set property TasksAccounting, or unknown property.\"".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same here after a clean CentOS install. It was fixed after running:

```
yum -y update
reboot
```

Comment: Ran into same issue and this helped. Did not need to reboot. Just restart Docker.

Answer (score 1):

Updating systemd would be enough. ([source](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/issues/2096#issuecomment-558090083))

```
yum update systemd
```